# ¿como capturar el touch de forma horizontal y vertical?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

hola amigos programadores como estan espero que muy bien
tengo un problema al momento de tratar de captura el movimiento vertical y horizontal de la pantalla de mi android tengo el sigiente codigo

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    cory = (int) event.getY();
    corx = (int) event.getY();
    posInicial = corx;
    if(posInicial<cory){
        tvUsurio.setText(volumen+1);
        return true;
    }else if (posInicial>cory){
        tvUsurio.setText("Bajo volumne");
        return true;
    }
   return true;
}
```

el problema es que no me muestra nada cuando toco la pantalla no me muestra nada podrían ayudarme con esto ademas no se si asi esta bien o que

Comment: echale un ojo a  [GestureDetector] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html ) que te permite tratar diferentes eventos

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que si realizas un movimiento hacia arriba subes el volumen y si realizas un movimiento hacia abajo baja el volumen. En base a lo anterior se trabajaría con las coordenadas del eje Y.

Es importante recordar que en Android las coordenadas son indicadas de esta forma, en la esquina superior izquierda tenemos X = 0, Y = 0 y va a aumentando Y hacia abajo y X hacia la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para realizar lo que deseas, primero tienes que obtener el valor de Y y compararlo con `posInicial`, después de la comparación almacenas el valor de y en la variable `posInicial`.

Con esto puedes realizar lo que deseas, recuerda que el listener para usar el método onTouch() es [OnTouchListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

Agrego un ejemplo, suponiendo tener un `LinearLayout` como fondo en nuestro layout principal `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout">   
</LinearLayout>
```

Dentro de nuestra Activity que carga el layout obtenemos la referencia y asignamos el listener:

```
  LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        my_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                if(posInicial > y){
                    Log.i("Volumen", "Sube volumen!");
                    //tvUsurio.setText(volumen+1);
                }else if (posInicial < y){
                    Log.i("Volumen", "Baja volumen!");
                    //tvUsurio.setText("Bajo volumne");
                }

                //Despues de evaluar si va hacia arriba o hacia abajo almacenamos el valor de la variable.
                posInicial = y;

                return true;
            }
        });
```